# How to use an exponential easing function while using Transform.RotateAround?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interpolation, lerp

I have a scene where a cube-shaped object "rolls" on a flat surface. Each time, it completes a 90-degree rotation around `pivotPoint` (the edge making contact with the surface) over the `pivotAxis` (perpendicular to the direction of movement). For this, the `Transform.RotateAround` function seemed appropriate, as it allows me to supply those parameters and apply the necessary position change that comes with this kind of off-center rotation. The movement has a time constraint of `totalDuration`.

This is inside the coroutine where movement is applied:

```
timePassed = 0f;
while (timePassed < totalDuration)
        {
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
            rotationAmount = (Time.deltaTime / totalDuration) * 90f;
            cube.RotateAround(pivotPoint, pivotAxis, rotationAmount);

            // Track rotation progress in case the function is interrupted
            offBalanceDegrees += rotationAmount;

            yield return null;
        }
// snap position and rotation of cube to final value, then repeat
```

This works well enough and gives me linear movement, as the `rotationAmount` in each iteratio is the same. However, I'd like this to feature an easing function to start off slowly and finish quickly. I must still be able to specify a `pivotPoint`, `pivotAxis` and `totalDuration`, and I'm a bit stuck as to how I could accomplish this.

Other examples I've seen applied rotation around the object's centre, which is a simpler case than what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a linear `t` between 0 and 1, you can use `tnew = t * t * t;` to get a cubic `tnew`. Then you just need to reconfigure your equation to use a `t` that goes from 0 to 1.

Altogether, this might look like this:

```
timePassed = 0f;
offBalanceDegrees = 0f;
while (timePassed < totalDuration)
{
    timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

    float t = timePassed / totalDuration
    t = t * t * t;

    // Track rotation progress in case the function is interrupted
    oldRotationAmount = offBalanceDegrees;
    offBalanceDegrees = t * 90f;

    cube.RotateAround(pivotPoint, pivotAxis, offBalanceDegrees - oldRotationAmount);

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks!